# Android: Mapping from preview image to image displayed in SurfaceView

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I cannot figure out the correspondence / mapping between image received in PreviewCallback, and image displayed on SurfaceView (setPreviewDisplay).

Problem :

1. Center of Preview Callback image and Center of preview displayed on the SurfaceView is not same.
2. It appears that when camera preview has an aspect ratio different than that of SurfaceView and images are bigger than SurfaceView, the SurfaceView crops and / or scales them in some way. But I could not find any document which tells how exactly.

Other : 
I have to do some image processing , find relevant point and then show markers on display corresponding to those points. Converting YUV to RGB in PreviewCallback and then drawing on Canvas is not an option as it is very slow.